# code on jsfiddle vs active server (code on active server isn't working correctly)

Tags: jquery

Here is my problem, I put a piece of code in jsfiddle, and it works perfectly.  I put the same code on my website, obviously adding in the header to include jquery and jquery UI (links directly to jquery sites, not hosting those files locally) and the code doesn't work.

I am attempting to get a "sortable" effect to work in this project.  Its not just this code either.  Its been every single piece of code that has anything draggable, movable, etc. that uses jquery.  I'm missing something and can't even think of what it is.

I own the servers in the datacenter, and they are running cPanel, so I have full access to the server itself if I need to make changes.

When I test the code on jsfiddle, when i click and drag the

tags, it doesn't highlight the text and it moves the `<li>` tags allowing me to reorder the list.  On my website, it starts highlighting the text and doesn't actually move the file.  All the HTML is exactly the same on both places.

Any ideas?

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yGrUp/

Code: (some of the code is still there that interacts with my php code; however, removed all the php code for this example for testing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
/* when the DOM is ready */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* grab important elements */
    var sortInput = jQuery('#sort_order');
    var submit = jQuery('#autoSubmit');
    var messageBox = jQuery('#message-box');
    var list = jQuery('#sortable-list');
    /* create requesting function to avoid duplicate code */
    var request = function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                messageBox.text('Updating the sort order in the database.');
            },
            complete: function() {
                messageBox.text('Database has been updated.');
            },
            data: 'sort_order=' + sortInput[0].value + '&ajax=' + submit[0].checked + '&do_submit=1&byajax=1', //need [0]?
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>'
        });
    };
    /* worker function */
    var fnSubmit = function(save) {
        var sortOrder = [];
        list.children('li').each(function(){
            sortOrder.push(jQuery(this).data('id'));
        });
        sortInput.val(sortOrder.join(','));
        console.log(sortInput.val());
        if(save) {
            request();
        }
    };
    /* store values */
    list.children('li').each(function() {
        var li = jQuery(this);
        li.data('id',li.attr('title')).attr('title','');
    });
    /* sortables */
    list.sortable({
        opacity: 0.7,
        update: function() {
            fnSubmit(submit[0].checked);
        }
    });
    list.disableSelection();
    /* ajax form submission */
    jQuery('#dd-form').bind('submit',function(e) {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();
        fnSubmit(true);
    });
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<ul id="sortable-list">
<li title="1">Item 1</li>
<li title="2">Item 2</li>
<li title="3">Item 3</li>
<li title="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two* opening script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
/* when the DOM is ready */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

The second one is treated as JavaScript code, and fails to parse. You should be getting an error in the dev tools console; for instance, Chrome says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

To fix it, simply remove one of them. (It works on jsFiddle because you didn't paste the script tags in.)

Comment: I can't believe thats all it was.  Well, sorta.  I realized on my live code as well I used a min.js version of jquery which didn't allow the code to work either.  But thank you for noticing that mistake that I completely missed.  I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.